# How to check if the connection with Redis can be established?

Tags: php, docker, redis, phpredis

I have Redis container running in Docker and I use phpredis to work with it. I wonder whether I can check if a connection can be established before calling 'connect' method? Because if Redis container is stopped and I have
`$redis_client = new Redis(); $redis_client->connect( 'host_name', 'port_name', 5 );`
I will get a warning that will impact application's performance. I know about 'ping' method but it is intended to check the connection after 'connect' is called.

I tried calling 'ping' before 'connect' and expected it will tell me whether connection is possible or not but in this case I got an exception from Redis ("Redis server went away").

Comment: Unless you actually try to connect, how do you think you could tell if it was possible to connect? The only way to verify that is to attempt a connection. On a more basic level you could try to establish a raw socket connection to check if the port is open, which could give you an indication, but that doesn't necessarily prove that the service is fully up and running.